# PHP PDO unnamed bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo

I try to make a specific MySQL query work with PDO unnamed placeholders, and I suspect the problem might have something to do with the ' ' around the third question mark, but I just can't figure it out.

I get the exception:
'Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'

Here's the relevant parts of the function, try-catch and the like removed for ease of reading. Function is called with $column and $mytype containing simple alphanumeric strings that worked fine with the earlier pure MySQL code, before I changed it to PDO-MySQL, so they should be ok.

```
define('SQL_TABLE', 'mytable');

function listThem($column, $mytype) {

   # These lines succeed
   $databaseHandle = new PDO('mysql:host=' . SQL_HOST . ';dbname=' . SQL_DATABASE, SQL_USER, SQL_PASSWORD);
   $databaseHandle->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

   # The following three lines cast the exception
   $input = array(SQL_TABLE, $column, $mytype);
   $statementHandle = $databaseHandle->prepare('SELECT *, ((100 * likes) / (dislikes + 1)) '
      . "AS rating FROM ? WHERE ? REGEXP '?' ORDER BY rating DESC;");
   $statementHandle->execute($input);

   # . . .  more code here
}
```

Comment: is the REGEXP referring to this one ? https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp - if it is you might want to check your syntax for it

Comment: I don't recall being able to bind a table name as a parameter in your query.

Comment: thanks! I am not sure which REGEXP implementation I use, but it shouldn't matter as it worked fine before I started rewriting the code for PDO, with no changes to the regexps. I get the exception even when $mytype is just a simple six-letter lowercase string with no spaces, so I'd guess the error is hiding somewhere else...

Comment: Thanks arxanas! You were on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't bind table or field names as arguments using prepared statements. Parameter binding is only for values.

You will need to build those into the string. Just make sure you filter the values properly.

Also, you should not need to use '?', bound arguments take care of this.

Comment: That took care of it. Thanks! And thanks for the improvement of the '?'.